# Getting "Socket is not connected" errors when trying to access anything via ALProxy in NAOqi for virtual robot

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, nao-robot, choregraphe

I'm trying to create a Python API to interface with a NAO robot, and have been testing on the Choregraphe virtual robot. As of 24 hours ago, seemingly out of nowhere, this stopped working because whenever I run:

`foo = ALProxy(ALfunction, ip, port)`

and try to use it like:

`foo.do()`

I get the error:

RuntimeError:   ALfunction::do
Socket is not connected

Real example:

```
def sayText(args, ip, port):
    tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", ip, port)
    print(str(args[0]))
    tts.say(str(args[0]))
```

when run, will give:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\naoqi.py", line 371, in method_missing
raise e
RuntimeError:   ALTextToSpeech::say
Socket is not connected

What is the issue? How can I fix it?

This issue originally occurred on my laptop from the very start, and so I have been working on my PC where the issue seemingly just did not occur. I thought it might be a firewall thing, but clearly not since I didn't change any settings between yesterday and today.

Beyond that I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: Further information required. Is this TCP or UDP? If TCP, is it the server or the client? Where is the code that actually deals with the socket?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the right port ? The port of the virtual robot from Choregraphe can change.

You can find that port in edit -> preferences -> virtual robot, down at the bottom.

Also, make sure that the virtual robot is actually running in Choregraphe, you can connect to him in Choregraphe to make sure he appears in the 3D view.